# flutter / how to add maps to list of maps

Tags: flutter, dart, maps

I want to add datas  I pull from firebase.I store my data in sting clases . I want to pull that data from firebase. and add to local map list so I can acces quickly and easly.

```
` dynamic getData(Map data, List<String> way) {
    dynamic dataTemp = data;
    if (way.length > 0) {
      for (int x=0; x < way.length; x++) {
        dataTemp = dataTemp[way[x]];
      }
    }
    return dataTemp;
  }

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> locations = [
 {
      'country': 'Japan',
      'city': 'Tokyo',
      'Latitude': 35.6762,
      'Longitude': 139.6503,
      'utcOffset': 9,
      'example' : {
        'data'   : "text",
        'number' : 20,
        'boolean': false
       }
    }
];


 getData(locations[0],["example","number"]);`
```

in this example how can I add multiple of .

```
` {
  'country': 'Japan',
  'city': 'Tokyo',
  'Latitude': 35.6762,
  'Longitude': 139.6503,
  'utcOffset': 9,
  'example' : {
    'data'   : "text",
    'number' : 20,
    'boolean': false
   }
}`
```

this code

from my firebase database ?

Comment: You can add map in List<Map<String, dynamic>> _list = [{"key":"value"}];

Answer (score 0):

Use .asMap()

Example:

```
List mylist = [];
mylist.add(locations);
final myMap = mylist.asMap();

print(myMap[0][0]['example']); // {data: text, number: 20,boolean: false} 
print(myMap[0][0]['example']['number']); // 20
```